# Neo4j aggregate function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use the `SUM` function and store the result of it as a new property of the relationship. But it is not working. 
The query I used is :

```
MATCH (a:Employee)-[r:CorporateMessage]->(b)
WHERE a.Eid = 6001 AND b.Eid IN [6002,6003,6004,6005,5001]
SET r.Internalsum = SUM(r.Count)
```

The error i got was:

> Invalid use of aggregating function sum(...) in this context (line 1, column 124 (offset: 123)) "MATCH (a:Employee)-[r:CorporateMessage]->(b)WHERE a.Eid = 6001 AND b.Eid IN [6002,6003,6004,6005,5001] SET r.Internalsum = SUM(r.Count)"

Kindly explain what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
MATCH (a:Employee)-[r:CorporateMessage]->(b)
WHERE a.Eid = 6001 AND b.Eid IN [6002,6003,6004,6005,5001]
WITH r, SUM(r.count) as count
SET r.Internalsum = count
```

Always put [aggregation functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) in `WITH` or `RETURN`.

Comment: Thank you...but when i tried it I am getting this error: Variable `r` not defined (line 4, column 5 (offset: 135))
"SET r.Internalsum = count"

Comment: Hi! Edited the answer! :)
I was forgot to pass `r` to the next context in the `WITH`.

Comment: Thank you dear!..it worked...could you explain why it didn't work with previous statement.

Comment: The `WITH` is used to chain queries, passing parts from the previous to the next query. In the previous statement I was forgot to add the `r` variable to the `WITH` clause. Thus `r` was undefined in the next context (context of `SET` in your case). It is clear? You can se the [WITH doc here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/).